# Логика графов

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем, привет! Есть данные для построения графов:

```
a -- b
a -- c
a -- d
```

если построить граф то получим:

[image]

Необходимо пронумеровать результат, точка отчета известна, она всегда будет начинаться "C" в итоге нужно получить:

```
а:0; b:1; d:2
```

Какие есть предложения товарищи?

Comment: Ну так что мешает их нумировать-то? ))

Обходите граф, каждый узел помечаете числом, после отметки текущего узла это число увеличиваете - и все)

Как надо обходить? Есть различные способы обхода, см. википедию - [поиск в глубину](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83), [поиск в ширину](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Comment: Спасибо! Пробовать делать)